# Как можно узнать, в каком именно сайдбаре отображается виджет?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Хочу добавить виджет в top bar. Для этого его нужно вывести без заголовка. Нашел хук `widget_title`, позволяющий заменить заголовок.

Нужно это сделать только в определенном сайдбаре.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во время вызова виджета не выполняются никакие хуки, которые можно было было соотнести с сайдбаром. Поэтому не остаётся ничего иного, кроме как анализировать стек вызовов.

Пример кода ниже прячет заголовок (возвращает пустую строку), если виджет с именем `'Search'` в админке вызван в сайдбаре с именем `'Sidebar'`. Код рабочий, проверен на теме `twentysixteen`.

```
function my_widget_title( $title, $instance, $id_base ) {
    if ( 'Search' === $instance['title'] ) {
        $callers = debug_backtrace();
        foreach ( $callers as $caller ) {
            if ( 'dynamic_sidebar' === $caller['function'] ) {
                $sidebar_index = $caller['args'][0];
                $sidebar_name  = $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'][ $sidebar_index ]['name'];
                if ( 'Sidebar' === $sidebar_name ) {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'widget_title', 'my_widget_title', 10, 3 );
```

Код надо добавить в `functions.php` вашей темы.

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает.